# Laravel 5 Composer update fails

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

After upgrading a Laravel project from 5.0 to 5.1.x, I can not run a composer update correctly.
The app itself works fine and no problems, but will need composer to work.

This is the error I am receiving after running `sudo composer update`

```
[LogicException]                                                                                               
  The command defined in "Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateMakeCommand" cannot have an empty name.  
    Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

    [RuntimeException]  
    Error Output:
```

When trying to debug the file `Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateMakeCommand` I can not find any noticable error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I received this same error when upgrading to 5.1. My problem was with the php version, it must be `>= 5.5.9`.

Comment: @user2094178 thanks...I'm using 5.6.2 though

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is giving its best to maintain the relationship first of all you need to have 2 model or you can say two table for relation and the respestive columns now you need to specify whether it has relation of one to one or one to many or many to many then you can simple specify it on model. As your tables are not specific tables so you can see the example like relation between users table and questions table relation here is one to many . One user can have many question while one question is belong to the user now In my Questions model the realtion looks like public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

now in the user model my code looks like 
        return $this->hasMany('App\Questions');
    }

be sure you have maintained foreign key while migrating :) for more you can see here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships hope this would help